# What's the before block without the :each or :all parameter in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm familiar with the Rspec's `before` blocks.

For example,

```
before(:each) do
  # some setup code before each test
end
```

and

```
before(:all) do
  # some setup code before all the tests
end
```

But I have seen

```
before do
  # some code
end
```

How is this `before` without any parameter different from `before(:each)` and `before(:all)`?  If it's different, when is it executed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
before do
  # some code
end
```

Is simply shorthand for

```
before(:each) do
  # some code
end
```